# How to prevent window popup when new program starts?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, popups

Say I launch Firefox when reading a PDF. To prevent distraction, I want it to open silently until I manually switch to it. Is there a way to do this? All the search result I found is about JavaScript popup. I can use AutoHotKey.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/771194